# sum of all numbers in a text file without knowing how many lines or how many numbers per line

Tags: python

How could I make a program that sums up all numbers in a txt file like this:

```
12 49 1 4 5
4 5
14
20
4 5 91
etc..
```

I was thinking of doing for line in readline(), then checking if there are spaces in the line and splitting it if there is. How would I go about and do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by reading the entire file content - i.e., no need to read one line at a time. Note how str.split() is called with no parameters which will have the effect of splitting on whitespace.

```
with open('test.txt') as test:
    print(sum(map(int, test.read().split())))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split with the default whitespace splitting, and convert the strings to `int`s, which can be done with a simple `map`. All in all, the following is a consice way of getting the sum you want:

```
with open('/path/to/file/numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    full_sum = sum(map(int, f.read().split()))
print(full_sum)
```

The whole thing is a single line after getting a handle on the open file.

Breaking it down for clarity though, you can do the following:

```
row_sums = []
with open('/path/to/file/numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    for r in f.readlines():
        row_sum = sum(map(int, r.split()))
        row_sums.append(row_sum)
full_sum = sum(row_sums)
print(full_sum)
```